# Change direction of a specific column header to RTL Telerik Report Table

Tags: c#, telerik, right-to-left

I have a problem with the direction of a specific column in Telerik Table Group.
With firebug I can find and change the direction of a table from *LTR* to *RTL* when I use two languages (Arabic/English).

BUt how can I change the direction of a specific column header and not the entire row or table in telerik Table Group?

**Note** : I use C# With Telerik Report R3 2017

Comment: Can you provide more information about the firebug loko around? Perhaps you can add a style to this column and add it to your css, If the element do not have a .culture, you can try to add a label and set it's .culture; If you just want to apply firebug workaround you can also build a js when the report viewer is loaded to make the edit.

Comment: ِAdd  `css` file to change  direction you mean ?